# How to keep Wrapper component's size

Tags: reactjs, typescript

https://codesandbox.io/s/restless-glade-uynlwv?file=/src/App.tsx

I'm making an app that increases the number of squares as the stage rises when a square with a different color or transparency is clicked in each square.
The problem I'm having right now is that the size of the Wrapper component is increasing every time the stage goes up.
I want to keep the size of the `Wrapper` component that wraps each rectangle even when the stage increases. Is there a way?

[image]

[image]

[image]

As shown in the picture above, I want the size of the Wrapper component to be maintained regardless of the stage increase.